# Which open source project would you recommend contributing to?

Tags: language-agnostic, open-source

What open source projects would you recommend as a good place for a starting open source developer? Factors that I think would be important are some obvious ones like well written code and a community that is helpful to newbies. But it might be nice if the code base is such that I can start hacking some small problems without really understanding the details of how everything works.

I'd prefer something that can be developed on Linux using C/C++/Java/Python/Scala.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Trying to pick a project like that will never work because it's not something you're passionate about.  What's an open source project that you use daily or enjoy using?  Go work with that one.

Comment: Well said, Most Open source projects were started to 'scratch an itch'. If you don't have the same itch what will be the motivation.

Comment: You may work on the larger projects to up your resume a bit, thats motivation enough. Not everything has to be a labour of love.

Comment: Well, I run Ubuntu and a more or less completely open-source stack. So, the list isn't small. :-) 

Also, I'm not convinced about this 'scratch an itch' theory. Some of my best work for my company was not software that I used daily. A lot of problems can be interesting without being relevant.

Comment: @Pramod,
Wish I could vote up comments ;^)~

Comment: ditto - if you're not passionate about the project, don't waste your time on it. Get a side-job instead and invest the money for retirement ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what your interests are as to what project to dive into.

Rationale for a larger project (e.g. Firefox, OpenOffice, etc) is that it has many developers, a well established code base, and many small tasks/bugs to be worked out.

Rationale for a smaller project is that you will become more intimate with the code and application. You will likely get to know other developers on the team and understand the overall concept better. Additionally, your additions to the project may be more noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

**sourceforge** has a list of projects seeking a new developer. Therer are several for your requested programming languages:

http://sourceforge.net/people/?category_id=1

Apart  from developers they have more help requests:

http://sourceforge.net/people/

Answer (score 1):

Pick one you use and like already.